# Can't send proper post request with file using python3 requests

Tags: python-3.x, api, file-upload, python-requests, multipartform-data

I was using Postman to send post request like on the screenshot

[image: screen from postman with successful request]

Now I need to implement it in python. This is what i've got for now:

```
import requests

data = {"sendRequest": {"apiKey": 12345, "field1": "field1value"}}
files = {"attachment": ("file.txt", open("file.txt", "rb"))}
headers = {"Content-type": "multipart/form-data"}
response = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers=headers, files=files)
```

But still it's not working - server doesn't accept it as valid request. I've tried more combinations but without any results and I really couldn't find a solution.
I need this request to be exactly like that one in postman

Comment: Where is the rest of the code? You are just declaring stuff here.

Comment: There is requests.post(). After that I'm printing response and response.content. That's all. The problem I have is not that specific code, but that I can't get exactly same effect like postman does. Server accepts postman request as you can see on the screenshot but doesn't accept this request from python.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I used MultipartEncoder from requests_toolbelt library.

```
from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
import requests
import json

data = {"apiKey": 12345, "field1": "field1value"}}
mp = MultipartEncoder(
    fields={
        'sendRequest': json.dumps(data), # it is important to convert dict into json
        'attachment': ('file.pdf', open('file.pdf', 'rb'), 'multipart/form-data'),
    }
)
r = requests.post(ENDPOINT, data=mp, headers={'Content-Type': mp.content_type})
```